# function declaration and call and definition in c

Tags: c, loops

Why is this code not running after printing of array if I take value of n>=9?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float mean_function(float array[],int n);
int main() {
    int i,n;
    float array[n],mean,sum=0,s2,summation,deno,C[i],elements;
    printf("Enter No of Elements\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter Elements\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%f",&array[i]);
        printf("%f",array[i]);
    }
    printf("sample variance(s2) : (sum((x-mean)*(x-mean)))/(n-1) /n");
    printf("population variance(sigma2) : (sum((x-u)*(x-u))/n");
    mean_function(array,n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        deno=((array[i]-mean)*(array[i]-mean));
        C[i]=deno;
        summation=summation+C[i];
    }
    s2=((summation)/(n-1));
    printf("s2=%f \n",s2);
}
float mean_function(float array[],int n) {
    int i;
    float sum=0,mean;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){ sum=sum+array[i]; }
    mean=(sum/n);
    return mean;
}
```

Comment: How are you declaring `array`? What is your expected output? What problems you are facing with the given code? please post [mcve].

Comment: _"why is this code not running after printing of array if I take value of n>=9???"_ may be your array is just < 9, there is nothing in your question that indicates size of the array yet

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
float mean_function(float array[],int n);
int main()
{
int i,n;
float array[n],mean,sum=0,s2,summation,deno,C[i],elements;
printf("Enter No of Elements\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Enter Elements\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
scanf("%f",&array[i]);
printf("%f",array[i]);
}
printf("sample variance(s2) : (sum((x-mean)*(x-mean)))/(n-1) /n");
printf("population variance(sigma2) : (sum((x-u)*(x-u))/n");    
mean_function(array,n);    
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
deno=((array[i]-mean)*(array[i]-mean));
C[i]=deno;
summation=summation+C[i];

Comment: }
s2=((summation)/(n-1));
printf("s2=%f \n",s2);
}
float mean_function(float array[],int n)
{
 int i;
    float sum=0,mean;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
sum=sum+array[i];
}
mean=(sum/n);
return mean;
}

Comment: this is the full code . if I enter the value of n 9 or greater than 9 the code runs only till printing of array .otherwise it is executed

Comment: Please to not extend your question in comments. Add stuff as update to the question itself. There is an "edit"-button below it.

Answer (score 0):

The code is likely not running because `array[n]` is declared with an uninitialized `n`. At the time you read `n` with scanf(), the array does not automatically "grow into the right size". You should either declare `array` big enough, or if you really want it to be user-defined, use malloc to allocate it (read the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/questions.html)) and all Stackoverflow questions tagged array...)

In addition, the scanf at some point fails. Note that when you enter numbers, you also have the "Enter" as a newline (`'\n'`) in the input stream. You never read the newline so the next scanf fails.

This becomes obvious when you actually check the return value from scanf with code like this:

```
if (scanf("%f", &array[i]) == 1) {
   /* successfully converted 1 item */
}
else {
   /* scanf failed */
}
```

Usually what you want is to skip whitespace in the input. You do this by placing a space in the scanf format. Note that a single space tells scanf to skip *any* amount of white-space.

```
if (scanf(" %f", &array[i]) == 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this code not running after printing of array if I take value
>   of n>=9?

Some thoughts about your code (and about building programs in steps):

1. Arrays in C don't change in size once defined. VLAs are out for a variety of reasons. malloc() is in.
2. Use double, unless there is a specific reason to use floats.
3. Define and initialize one variable per line. Uninit vars can only result in an error as mentioned by @Jens.
4. Function declarations at the top (which you have done)
5. During development, there is no need to complicate things with a scanf (at least initially). It only adds an unwarranted layer of complexity. If you are testing statistical functions (mean, variance), put numbers in a pre-defined static array and verify functionality first.
6. C[i] as been declared with uninitialized i.
7. For this initial phase of building this program, I include a basic program.
8. I am not a fan of zero space between tokens (but ignore that)
9. Consider calling your array something other than 'array'.
10. Calculating the size of the samples array allows you to change the number of elements without changing anything else in code; which adds another layer of complexity to an already difficult phase.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double sample_mean(double* p, int n);
int main()
{
    double samples[] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 16.5, 2.3};
    double mean = 0.0;

    int size_samples = sizeof samples/sizeof(double);
    printf("size_samples = %d\n", size_samples);

    mean = sample_mean(samples, size_samples);
    printf("Mean = %.2lf", mean);

}
// -------------------------------
double sample_mean(double* p, int n)
{
    double mean = 0.0;
    double total = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        total += *p++;
    mean = total/n;

    return mean;
}
```

---

Once this functionality is present (saved), you can start working on other stat functions. This way you can work step by step to get closer to the desired outcome.
Next up you can define `sample_variance(double* p, int n)` and work on that knowing that additional(new errors) are not coming from your code written so far.
Output:

```
size_samples = 8

Mean = 5.24
```

I hope it helps.